# Response code 400 is returned when specifying a specific scope on GoogleTV

Tags: google-fit

**Question**
When I specify a specific scope, a response code of 400 is returned and I am unable to go to the authentication screen.

【400 error scope】
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.heart_rate.read
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.blood_pressure.read
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.body_temperature.read

【200 OK scope】
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.body.read
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read

If you know why the response code is different between 200 and 400 even though it is the same FitnessApi, please let me know.
Also, the scope for profile and email is returned at 200 normally.

**Notes**
**Google Cloud Platform Settings**

- We have enabled the FitnessAPI.
- For authentication information, client ID and client secret are generated using "Client ID for TVs and devices with limited input functions".
- The Fitness scope described above is set in the OAuth consent screen settings of the Google Cloud Platform.

**Relevant source**

```
    private static final String OAUTH_CODE_URL = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/device/code";
    private static final String OAUTH_TOKEN_URL = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token";
    private static final String SCOPE_FITNESS_BODY = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.body.read";
    private static final String SCOPE_FITNESS_ACTIVITY = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read";
    private static final String SCOPE_FITNESS_HEART_RATE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.heart_rate.read";
    private static final String SCOPE_FITNESS_BLOOD_PRESSURE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.blood_pressure.read";
    private static final String SCOPE_FITNESS_BODY_TEMPERATURE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.body_temperature.read";
    private static final String SCOPE_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String SCOPE_PROFILE = "profile";
：
    public Object[] postAccessToken() {
        String postBody = "client_id=" + OAUTH_CLIENT_ID +
                "&scope=" + SCOPE_EMAIL +
                "%20" + SCOPE_FITNESS_BODY_TEMPERATURE  + 
                "%20" + SCOPE_FITNESS_ACTIVITY +          
                "%20" + SCOPE_FITNESS_BODY +              
                "%20" + SCOPE_FITNESS_HEART_RATE +        
                "%20" + SCOPE_FITNESS_BLOOD_PRESSURE +    
                "%20" + SCOPE_PROFILE;
        return postAPI(OAUTH_CODE_URL, postBody);
    }
：

    public Object[] postAPI(String sendUrl, String sendPostData) {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        String result = "";
        String str = "";
        int statusCode = 0;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(sendUrl);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            String postData = sendPostData;
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(5000);
            urlConnection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android");
            urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", Locale.getDefault().toString());
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();
            outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "utf-8"));
            bufferedWriter.write(postData);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();

            // Get the response code
            statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
```

Answer (score 0):

OAuth 2.0 flow for TV and limited-input device applications have [limited access scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/limited-input-device#allowedscopes). However, these scopes are supported for other authentication flows, such as for mobile/desktop apps, and web apps.

The OAuth 2.0 flow for TV is supported only for the following scopes:

- email
- openid
- profile